# Tweepy Stream Listener for Extended Tweets

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am using the Stream Listener of Tweepy and wanted to retrieve tweets around the current political debate in the UK. Unfortunately, I only get truncated tweets in the case of RTs and responses.

Such as:-

> RT @ZaidJilani: Chuck Schumer (sponsor of antiBDS bill) says we should be strangling Gaza. Jeremy Corbyn says oppressing them will…

When the fulltweet should be:-

> Chuck Schumer (sponsor of antiBDS bill) says we should be strangling Gaza. Jeremy Corbyn says oppressing them will only radicalize people.

I have seen that there is a way to use `tweet_mode=extended with the regular Twitter.API. However I cannot find something similar with the Streaming API. Has anyone a solution for this? My code is as follows:-

```
 from tweepy import Stream
 from tweepy import OAuthHandler
 from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
 from redis import Redis
 from rq import Queue
 import requests
 import time
 import io
 import os
 import json
 import threading
 import multiprocessing
 from datetime import datetime, timedelta
 import _credentials

 # twitter OAuth
 ckey = _credentials.ckey
 consumer_secret = _credentials.consumer_secret
 access_token_key = _credentials.access_token_key
 access_token_secret = _credentials.access_token_secret



 #Listener Class Override
 class listener(StreamListener):

def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit):
    self.time = start_time
    self.limit= time_limit
    self.tweet_data = []



def on_data(self, data):
    localtime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%b-%d--%H-%M-%S")
    print(localtime)

    while (time.time() - self.time) < self.limit:
        try:
            self.tweet_data.append(data)
            return True

        except BaseException:
            print ('failed ondata')
            time.sleep(5)
            pass
    saveFile = io.open(('raw_tweets_{}.json').format(localtime), 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    saveFile.write(u'[\n')
    saveFile.write(','.join(self.tweet_data))
    saveFile.write(u'\n]')
    saveFile.close()
    exit()



def on_error(self, status):

    print (status)

def on_disconnect(self, notice):

    print ('bye')




 #Beginning of the specific code
 keyword_list = ['Theresa May', 'Jeremy Corbyn', 'GE2017', 'Labour', 'Tory','Tories'] #track list

 start_time=time.time()
 auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, consumer_secret) #OAuth object
 auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
 twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener(start_time, time_limit=10)) #initialize           Stream object with a time out limit
 twitterStream.filter(track=keyword_list, languages=['en'])  #call the filter method to run the Stream Listener
```

Comment: The [Twitter Dev Documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets) states it is not available in the Streaming API - "The Streaming API does not provide the same ability to provide query parameters to configure request options. Therefore, the Streaming API will render all Tweets in compatibility mode at this time. [...] Tweets rendered in compatibility mode via the public REST API will not contain the extended_tweet field."

Answer (score 5):

update: support for tweet_mode = 'extended' appears to be added.

```js
self.stream = Stream(auth = auth, listener = self, tweet_mode= 'extended')
tweet_data = json.loads(data)
if "extended_tweet" in tweet_data:
    tweet = tweet_data['extended_tweet']['full_text']
```

PS. Excuse the formatting, spelling mistakes ect. I'm new to stack overflow and just wish to help others facing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Now that some time has passed, I think that full text is supported.

At this link:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates

It says compatibility is supported by default.  My (probably ugly) code that shows how I handle it is here:

```
    if 'extended_tweet' in raw_tweepy_data_object:
        if 'full_text' in raw_tweepy_data_object['extended_tweet']:
            text = raw_tweepy_data_object['extended_tweet']['full_text']
        else:
            pass # i need to figure out what is possible here
    elif 'text' in raw_tweepy_data_object:
        text = raw_tweepy_data_object['text']
```